# React Redux update UI with new data coming from API w/o user input

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, push, store

Can you guys help me find a solution for this problem:

Think Facebook, when another use gives me a "like" a get a notification immediately without the need for me to refresh the page.

How do I implement this using React Redux, how do I update the store based on data coming from my API, how can I detected changes coming from my API?

Comment: If you don't want to use sockets, you'd have to query the database in intervals..

Comment: as @k-wasilewski said you can use sockets which will broadcast the new likes and you can update your ui. But if don't wanna use this then somewhere in your app you can make a interval `setInterval` of certain time which will request new data from the api and updates it to the redux store.